# Characterization of pretty compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I believe that the following problem have already been considered by some sophisticated topologist.

**Definition 1.** A non-compact Hausdorff topological space $X$ is called *almost compact* if its Stone-Cech compactification coincides with its one point compactification.

An example of almost compact space is $[0,\omega_1)$ for first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$.

**Definition 2.** A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is called *pretty compact* if $X\setminus\{p\}$ is almost compact for all non-isolated points $p\in X$.

I would like to hear answers to any of the following questions.

**Questions:**

- What are examples of pretty compact spaces?
- Is it true that pretty compact spaces are extremally disconnected?
- Is it true that pretty compact spaces contain dense extremally disconnected subspace?
- Does there exist any characterization of pretty compact spaces?

Comment: I deleted my no longer relevant comments +1.

Comment: Are all *almost compact* spaces "large"? (I had to italicize because I confused myself rereading my sentence having all and almost right next to each other. Hah!)

Comment: @CameronWilliams, this is a soft question. In some sense they are large. Almost compact spaces are just 1 point behind their largest compactification.

Comment: There are hardly any "almost compact" spaces, so I expect a dearth of examples.

Comment: Indeed, the only two examples that I've found are from the book Pseudocompact topological spaces. M. Hrusak, A. Tamariz-Mascarua, M. Tkachenko. On the page 17 they say that $[0,\omega_1)$ is almost compact and Mrowka-Isbell space $\Psi(\mathcal{A})$ is almost compact for some specific maximal almost disjoint family in $2^\omega$.

Comment: At least consistently, pretty compact spaces need not be extremally disconnted:
By a result of [van Douwen, Kunen and van Mill](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill//papers/papers1989/canbe.pdf) $\beta \Bbb N \setminus \Bbb N$ is consistently pretty compact, but, as it is well-known, not extremally disconnected.

Comment: @Ulli, thank you for citing this paper!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question was partially answered on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382902/characterization-of-pretty-compact-spaces). It seems like there is no short clear description for such spaces since they include essentially different classes of topological spaces.